Sending real time data of audio recording through socket
I am trying to send chunks of a live recording through a socket using expo-file-system in react native.
The problem is that when I send chunks of the audio while it's still recording, the data turns out to be corrupted somehow, and when I decode it in my server I can't even play that audio.
But if I wait for the recording to be stopped and then start to send the data the audio turns out ok.
This is the function:

export async function uploadChunksToServer(recordingInstance, chunkSize, delayBetweenChunks) {
  let info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(recordingInstance.getURI());
  let uri = info.uri;
  let currentPosition = 0;
  let current_file_size = info.size;
  let prev_pos = 0;
  await sleep(delayBetweenChunks);

  do{

    try{

      let info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(recordingInstance.getURI());
      current_file_size = info.size;
       
        if (currentPosition + chunkSize >= current_file_size &&  currentPosition === prev_pos && prev_pos !== 0){
          console.log('blocked')
          continue;
        }
        else{
          const fileChunk = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
              encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
            })
            currentPosition += chunkSize;
            socket.emit('audioData', fileChunk);
          }
          prev_pos = currentPosition;
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    if (recordingInstance._isDoneRecording && current_file_size - currentPosition < chunkSize){
          const fileChunk = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
          encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
          position: currentPosition,
          length: current_file_size - currentPosition
        })
        currentPosition += current_file_size - currentPosition;
        socket.emit('recording', fileChunk);
        break
      }
  } while(currentPosition < current_file_size)

  console.log("final report >> ", currentPosition, current_file_size)
  console.log('exiting')

   const fileChunk = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
  })
  socket.emit('done_recording', fileChunk);

}




Here I sent the same audio twice and saved it in two files, once while recording and once after the recording stopped.
I compared them using Beyond Compare and noticed differences even at the start of the data inside the files.
Any info would be appreciated. Thanks!

  const recordingInstance = new Audio.Recording();
  await recordingInstance.prepareToRecordAsync({
    android:{
      extension: '.wav',
      linearPCMIsBigEndian:true,

    },
    ios:{
      extension: '.wav',
      linearPCMIsBigEndian:false,
      },

  });

Set the linearPCMIsBigEndian:false , and extension: '.wav' and it works.
IMPORTANT: The chunk length needs to be a multiple of 24!
